# What is the difference between a page and a node?

Tags: theming

What is the actual difference between a node and a page in Drupal 7? Why there is separate `page.tpl.php` and `node.tpl.php` pages. How is the theming applied for the actual page.

Any link for understanding all this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should start with the [Theming Guide](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme).

Comment: A node is basically a display type for an entry of a "Content Type". For example, if you create a content type called "Restaurants" which has fields "Name", "Address", "Phone Number".... then when you go an create a new piece of content of type "Restaurant", the URL will be something like www.yousite.com/node/* . The display of the fields for the new content you created at  www.yousite.com/node/* is determined by node.tpl.php.

On the other hand, page.tpl.php includes EVERYTHING you see in the page. So page.tpl.php is for EVERYTHING you see, and node.tpl.php is for node content only.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**node.tpl.php**

> Default theme implementation to display a node.

**page.tpl.php**

> Default theme implementation to display a single Drupal page.

see image for more detail.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Page.tpl.php contains, header, footer, left block and content section, while node.tpl.php contains content section

Answer (score 0):

Pages may hold nodes, blocks, modules.

In the other hand  nodes holds only articles, news, pictures, bla, bla.